# Computing conditional log odds of dependent variable with only one observation at a particular independent variable

Tags: regression, logistic, logit

I'm trying to understand logistic regression, and I keep getting hung up on the following point.  Let $Y$ be the dependent variable taking its values in ${0,1}$ with a single independent variable $X$ in the model, and let $p(x) = P(Y=1|X=x)$.  According to my understanding, what we're really doing is fitting a linear model to the log odds.  That is, we seek the maximum likelihood estimation of $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ where $$\log(p(x)/(1-p(x))) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x.$$  I'm confused, however, at how the left hand side is actually computed when this fit is made.  In particular, I don't understand how $p(x)$ is computed in the case that there is only a single observation at a particular X value.

By way of example, in the iris data set included in R, suppose I wanted to fit a logistic regression to determine whether the species is setosa (1), or not (0) with the independent variable Sepal.Length.  How does one compute $p(4.3)$ for the (singular) observation where Sepal.Length=4.3?

I came up against this when I tried to actually plot the linear function on the right side against the (observed) log odds computed from the data, and realized I had no idea how to compute the left side.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I think after you get you **intercept** and $\beta$ from the logistic regression you can directly calculate the probability for Sepal.Lenth=4.3

Here is the R code to do the logistic regression

```
iris$Species_new<-ifelse(iris$Species=='setosa',1,0) #recode the variable

myLogistic <- glm(Species_new ~ Sepal.Length, data = iris, family = "binomial")
```

results:

```
  #Call:  glm(formula = Species_new ~ Sepal.Length, family = "binomial",    data = iris)

  #Coefficients:
  #(Intercept)  Sepal.Length  
  #27.829        -5.176  

 #Degrees of Freedom: 149 Total (i.e. Null);  148 Residual
 #Null Deviance:      191 
 #Residual Deviance: 71.84        AIC: 75.84
```

Now your logistic regression model is:

$log\frac{p}{1-p}=27.829-5.176x \tag{1}$

$x$ is the Sepal.Length

Now Sepal.Length=$4.3$ plug this value into **(1)**

$log\frac{p}{1-p}=27.829-5.176*4.3$

It is easy to solve this equation:

$\frac{p}{1-p}=e^{(27.829-5.176*4.3)}$

Solve this we get $p=0.9962123$

Let us check what the computer get automatically,

```
p_i<-myLogistic$fit
p_i
```

You need to check the 14th data point for $p_i$ which is Sepal.Length=4.3

The $p$ is

```
0.9962154
```

It is almost the same as calculated by hand, the difference is only caused by different float point I think.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  But, isn't the quantity you've found above $\hat{p}$?  My understanding may be incorrect here, so let me try to explain another way.  In linear regression, the predicted $y$ values are $\hat{y}$ and the observed dependent variable values are $y_i$.  Since logistic regression is in essence linear regression where the dependent variable is the log-odds (I know the coefficients are computed differently), how would one find the analog to the $y_i$ values?  Or, how would one compute the residuals if we view logistic regression as linear regression with logit response?

Comment: The principal  with logistic regression is the same as linear regression.  You can check David W. Hosmer's Applied Logistic Regression second Editon p147 goodness of fit. The Hosmer-Lemshow Test part. The observed value is the observed frequency with some characteristics and predicted value are predicted frequency with the same characteristics.